# How can I sort a set of git commit IDs in topological order?

Tags: git

I have a set of commit SHA1s, in no particular order. I would like to pipe this set to a command, and have those commits returned in topological order.

Here's one way of doing this:

```
git rev-list --all --topo-order | grep --file SET_OF_SHA1S
```

As you can imagine, this is a very slow way of doing it, as `git rev-list` is having to print out all of the commit SHA1s, not just the ones in my set.

Is there a better and faster way to do this?

#### Use case:

My test framework tests certain Git commits and stores the result in a database. I'm writing a web page that summarises these results, and it would be nice to display the results in order. Sorting by commit date is not ideal as some rebased commits will have exactly the same commit date.

Comment: Note: `git rev-list --topo-order` will be faster with Git 2.20 (Q4 2018). See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53382508/6309).

Answer (score 9):

Here's one way of speeding it up:

```
git rev-list --topo-order $(cat SET_OF_SHA1S) \
   | grep --file SET_OF_SHA1S --max-count $(wc -l SET_OF_SHA1S)
```

Optimisations:

- Only ask `rev-list` to list all commits reachable from your set of SHA1s.
- As soon as `rev-list` prints enough commits that include the set of SHA1s you're interested in, tell `grep` to stop grepping using the `--max-count` parameter. `grep` will in turn close its input, and `rev-list` will stop needlessly printing out further SHA1s.

Comment: When the set of commits that you’re interested in is small compared to the repository size, and the commits are relatively close together in the history, it can be a significant improvement to exclude the parents of `git merge-base --all --octopus "${shas[@]}"` from the `rev-list` invocation.

Comment: @wchargin could you explain what that does?

Comment: @felixfbecker: `git rev-list HASH` will find and print out _all_ commits that are reachable from the given ref, which may be many thousands. Any commits that are common ancestors to all the commits in your `SET_OF_SHA1S` don’t affect the ordering and so can be omitted, in which case `rev-list` can stop walking as soon as it hits them.

Comment: @felixfbecker: For instance, on my machine running against the Linux repository, it takes 6.038s to run `git rev-list --topo-order 3829100a6372 bfafddd8de42`, but only 0.292s after excluding their merge base `811ba489fa52` (and computing the merge base itself takes only 0.313s).

Comment: If anybody struggles getting the above to work; the problem is with the 'wc -l SET_OF_SHA1S'. You need to do 'wc -l < SET_OF_SHA1S'; otherwise the filename is included.

Comment: git bash on windows, same small issue as *pveentjer* said - `wc -l foobar.txt` prints out `1234 foobar.txt` which adds garbage to grep command. Command needed a small fix to cut off the filename, `| cut -f1 -d' '` would do, but *pveentjer*'s trick with stdin (`<`) is so much shorter!

Answer (score 5):

<s>You can use `--no-walk` to prevent git from dumping any SHA-1s other than the ones you supply, and use `--topo-order` to force the correct order.</s>  As [Mort pointed out in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22714371/how-can-i-sort-a-set-of-git-commit-ids-in-topological-order/22725185?noredirect=1#comment57117649_22725185), this does not work.  The git documentation acquired new text noting (indirectly) this problem, as of git version 2.4.  (I consider this a bug in `git rev-list`, which should load enough of the commit graph to do the topological sort, then output just the user-specified revision IDs, in the correct order.)

My original script (left in here) therefore also does not work.  It can be made to work by removing the `--no-walk` from the step that generates temporary file `$TF2`, then using the contents of `$TF1` to extract and print the "interesting" revisions from their `$TF2` (sorted) order.

This is more or less what [Flimm's own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22714774/1256452) does.

[original answer, with flawed script, below]

---

I'm not sure exactly what I was doing with this code, but long ago, I wrote a script to check whether arguments supplied were in topo order:

```
#! /bin/sh
#
# check a list of IDs to see if they're in "topo order"
usage()
{
    echo "usage: $0 id [...]"
}

case $# in
0) usage 1>&2; exit 1;;
esac

TF1=$(mktemp)
TF2=$(mktemp)
trap "rm -f $TF1 $TF2; exit" 0 1 2 3 15

# parse the arguments into one file
git rev-parse $@ > $TF1 || exit 1
# and topo-sort the arguments into another
git rev-list --topo-order --no-walk --reverse $@ > $TF2 || exit 1
# If the list is in the correct order the files will be the same
cmp -s $TF1 $TF2 || {
    # If the files differ, it's possible that some argument(s) name
    # the same rev...
    [ $(wc -l < $TF1) -eq $(wc -l < $TF2) ] || {
        echo "ERROR: there are repeats in $@"
        # finding them is a pain, we don't bother trying
        exit 1
    }
    echo "ERROR: $@ NOT in topo order"
    echo "use instead:"
    # read the topo-ordered raw IDs
    while read sha1; do
        # and find the (single) arg in $@ that names this one
        for i; do
            if [ $(git rev-parse $i) = $sha1 ]; then
                printf ' %s' $i
                break
            fi
        done
    done < $TF2
    echo
    exit 1
}
echo "$@ in topo order"
exit 0
```

I *think* what I wanted here was to emit the same argument names, e.g., if you said `git-check-topo v1.7 1234567 branchX` it would tell you to use (literally) `branchX v1.7 1234567`, if that is what got you the right order, rather than just showing the raw SHA-1s.

For your purposes, a simple:

```
git rev-list --topo-order --no-walk $@
```

(with or without `--reverse` as desired) should work, I think.

Comment: I do not think `--no-walk` will do it. From the 2.6.2 docs you can see that --no-walk either outputs the commits int he order they were supplied or by date.
`        --no-walk[=(sorted|unsorted)]
           Only show the given commits, but do not traverse their ancestors. This has no effect if a range is specified. If the argument unsorted is given, the commits are shown in the order they were given on the command line. Otherwise (if sorted or no argument
           was given), the commits are shown in reverse chronological order by commit time. Cannot be combined with --graph.`

Comment: @Mort: interesting: that text was added in git 2.4.0.  Inspection of the source shows that it did indeed never work (the `--no-walk` flag causes the code to return before even attempting a topo-sort, probably because nothing has bothered to load enough of the graph to achieve it anyway).  The `rev-list` command doesn't *reject* the request, and it *could* do it (by doing the necessary walking, but keeping these commits internal-only); it just doesn't bother.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to speed up `git rev-list --topo-order` is to use Git 2.20 (Q4 2018)

See [commit 561b583](https://github.com/git/git/commit/561b583749b7428f1790f03164d0d0e75be71d7b), [commit b454241](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b45424181e9e8b2284a48c6db7b8db635bbfccc8), [commit 5284fc5](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5284fc5cc9791b6526b36909373748bc14daef1a), [commit f0d9cc4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f0d9cc4196a0188724866bc0b11a2e8e0f95ab36), [commit d6b4071](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d6b40712dc1733613ca8e05ac2f456f5ce4ddb41), [commit 4b47a9a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4b47a9a85ee43de37986721e5c5cb70f5652544b), [commit aca4240](https://github.com/git/git/commit/aca4240f6a32423df5f95de6a9354b524fe57ec5) (01 Nov 2018) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 62ca33e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/62ca33e02a4ea93dd59538ac986a082430253b27), 18 Nov 2018)</sup>

> ### `revision.c`: generation-based topo-order algorithm

> The current `--topo-order` algorithm requires walking all reachable commits up front, topo-sorting them, all before outputting the first value.
>
> This patch introduces a **new algorithm which uses stored generation numbers to incrementally walk in topo-order**, outputting commits as we go.
> This can dramatically reduce the computation time to write a fixed number of commits, such as when limiting with "`-n <N>`" or filling the first page of a pager.
>
> In my local testing, I used the following Git commands on the Linux repository in three modes:
>
> - `HEAD~1` with no commit-graph,
> - `HEAD~1` with a commit-graph, and
> - HEAD with a commit-graph.
>
> This allows comparing the benefits we get from parsing commits from the commit-graph and then again the benefits we get by restricting the set of commits we walk.
>
> ```
> Test: git rev-list --topo-order -100 HEAD
> HEAD~1, no commit-graph: 6.80 s
> HEAD~1, w/ commit-graph: 0.77 s
> HEAD, w/ commit-graph: 0.02 s
> ```

See all the details in [commit b454241](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b45424181e9e8b2284a48c6db7b8db635bbfccc8).

Note: as mentioned in [commit d6b4071](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d6b40712dc1733613ca8e05ac2f456f5ce4ddb41):

> The rev-list command is critical to Git's functionality.
>
> Here are a few important types of rev-list operations:
>
> - **Basic**: `git rev-list --topo-order HEAD`
> - **Range**: `git rev-list --topo-order compare..HEAD`
> - **Ancestry**: `git rev-list --topo-order --ancestry-path compare..HEAD`
> - **Symmetric Difference**: `git rev-list --topo-order compare...HEAD`

---

Do use Git 2.23 (Q3 2019) though, as a topo-orider from Git 2.20 introduced a regression when used on range.

See [commit 1d8e31a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1d8e31a3f63cbc8533bf763c6d4b89d8355769f0), [commit 1b4d882](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1b4d8827ff2303f2db209bb34614e53c98e82bd6) (21 May 2019) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit bdc81d1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/bdc81d15a238c4402cc493817086a0c50dc9a508), 17 Jun 2019)</sup>

> ### `revision`: keep `topo-walk` free of unintersting commits

> When updating the topo-order walk in [b454241](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b45424181e9e8b2284a48c6db7b8db635bbfccc8) (`revision.c`: generation-based topo-order algorithm, 2018-11-01, v2.20.0-rc0), the logic was a huge rewrite of the walk logic.
> In that massive change, we accidentally included the
> UNINTERESTING commits in `expand_topo_walk()`.
> This means that a simple query like
>
> ```
> git rev-list --topo-order HEAD~1..HEAD
> ```
>
> will expand the topo walk for all commits reachable from HEAD, and not
> just one commit.

> ### `revision`: use generation for `A..B --topo-order` queries

> If a commit-graph exists with computed generation numbers, then a
> '`git rev-list --topo-order -n <N> <rev>`' query will use those generation
> numbers to reduce the number of commits walked before writing `N` commits.
>
> One caveat put in b454241 (revision.c: generation-based topo-order
> algorithm, 2018-11-01) **was to not enable the new algorithm for queries
> with a revision range "`A..B`"**.
> The logic was placed to walk from "A" and mark those commits as uninteresting, but the performance was actually worse than the existing logic in some cases.
>
> The root cause of this performance degradation is that generation
> numbers *increase* the number of commits we walk relative to the
> existing heuristic of walking by commit date.
> While generation numbers actually guarantee that the algorithm is correct, the existing logic is very rarely wrong and that added requirement is not worth the cost.

---

With Git 2.28 (Q3 2020), "`git log -L...`" now takes advantage of the "which paths are touched by this commit?" info stored in the commit-graph system.

See [commit 002933f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/002933f3fe2b016022ebbbbb359f6aeba58309a4), [commit 3cb9d2b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3cb9d2b6f9fd2dcb17f5534fd1536682e76f734a), [commit 48da94b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/48da94ba374e0dca8d3a70c617060d94ce242c78), [commit d554672](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d5546726fb30b25b48f8475446261f997609ff1b) (11 May 2020) by [SZEDER Gábor (`szeder`)](https://github.com/szeder).
See [commit f32dde8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f32dde8c12d941065be848a9f66239df96bde216) (11 May 2020) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit c3a0282](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c3a02824cf938597bbbe7c2487db2c712adf5651), 09 Jun 2020)</sup>

> ### [`line-log`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/002933f3fe2b016022ebbbbb359f6aeba58309a4): try to use generation number-based topo-ordering
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: SZEDER Gábor</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> The previous patch made it possible to perform line-level filtering during history traversal instead of in an expensive preprocessing step, but it still requires some simpler preprocessing steps, notably topo-ordering.
>
> **However, nowadays we have commit-graphs storing generation numbers, which make it possible to incrementally traverse the history in topological order, without the preparatory `limit_list()` and `sort_in_topological_order()` steps**; see [b45424181e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b45424181e9e8b2284a48c6db7b8db635bbfccc8) ("`[`revision.c`](https`://github.com/git/git/blob/002933f3fe2b016022ebbbbb359f6aeba58309a4/revision.c): generation-based topo-order algorithm", 2018-11-01, Git v2.20.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/62ca33e02a4ea93dd59538ac986a082430253b27)).
>
> This patch combines the two, so we can do both the topo-ordering and the line-level filtering during history traversal, eliminating even those simpler preprocessing steps, and thus further reducing the delay before showing the first commit modifying the given line range.
>
> The '`revs->limited`' flag plays the central role in this, because, due to limitations of the current implementation, the generation number-based topo-ordering is only enabled when this flag remains unset.
>
> Line-level log, however, always sets this flag in `setup_revisions()` ever since the feature was introduced in [12da1d1f6f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/12da1d1f6ffcd546a892a33302bb34fd37169022) ("Implement line-history search (`git log -L`)", 2013-03-28, Git v1.8.4-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ed73fe56428eecd2b635473f6a517a183c4713a3)).
>
> The reason for setting '`limited`' is unclear, though, because the line-level log itself doesn't directly depend on it, and it doesn't affect how the `limit_list()` function limits the revision range.
>
> However, there is an indirect dependency: the line-level log requires topo-ordering, and the "traditional" `sort_in_topological_order()` requires an already limited commit list since [e6c3505b44](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e6c3505b44e943b73a01d9d48b442f8f49b0dfad) ("Make sure we generate the whole commit list before trying to sort it topologically", 2005-07-06, Git v0.99 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e6c3505b44e943b73a01d9d48b442f8f49b0dfad) listed in [batch #0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/)).
>
> The new, generation numbers-based topo-ordering doesn't require a limited commit list anymore.
>
> So don't set '`revs->limited`' for line-level log, unless it is really necessary, namely:
>
> - The user explicitly requested parent rewriting, because that is still done in the `line_log_filter()` preprocessing step (see previous patch), which requires `sort_in_topological_order()` and in `turn limit_list()` as well.
> - A commit-graph file is not available or it doesn't yet contain generation numbers.
>   In these cases we had to fall back on `sort_in_topological_order()` and in turn `limit_list()`.
>   The existing condition with `generation_numbers_enabled()` has already ensured that the '`limited`' flag is set in these cases; this patch just makes sure that the line-level log sets '`revs->topo_order`' before that condition.
>
> While the reduced delay before showing the first commit is measurable in [git.git](https://github.com/git/git), it takes a bigger repository to make it clearly noticable.
>
> In both cases below the line ranges were chosen so that they were modified rather close to the starting revisions, so the effect of this change is most noticable.
>
> ```
> # git.git
> $ time git --no-pager log -L:read_alternate_refs:sha1-file.c -1 v2.23.0
>
> Before:
>
> real    0m0.107s
> user    0m0.091s
> sys     0m0.013s
>
> After:
>
> real    0m0.058s
> user    0m0.050s
> sys     0m0.005s
>
> # linux.git
> $ time git --no-pager log \
>  -L:build_restore_work_registers:arch/mips/mm/tlbex.c -1 v5.2
>
> Before:
>
> real   0m1.129s
> user   0m1.061s
> sys    0m0.069s
>
> After:
>
> real   0m0.096s
> user   0m0.087s
> sys    0m0.009s
> ```
>
> Additional testing by Derrick Stolee: Since this patch improves the performance for the first result, I repeated the experiment from the previous patch on the Linux kernel repository, reporting real time here:
>
> ```
> Command: git log -L 100,200:MAINTAINERS -n 1 >/dev/null
>  Before: 0.71 s
>  After: 0.05 s
> ```
>
> Now, we have dropped the full topo-order of all ~910,000 commits before reporting the first result. The remaining performance improvements then are:
>
> 1. Update the parent-rewriting logic to be incremental similar to how "`git log --graph`" behaves.
> 2. Use `changed-path` Bloom filters to reduce the time spend in the tree-diff to see if the path(s) changed.

---

With Git 2.31 (Q1 2021), the topological walk codepath is covered by new trace2 stats.

See [commit 90b666d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/90b666da601a5ccf9bbc3f2282fb166bf3fdade7) (30 Dec 2020) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 02feca7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/02feca721eaf008c54d497d884232bd0c144edbb), 15 Jan 2021)</sup>

> ### [`revision`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/90b666da601a5ccf9bbc3f2282fb166bf3fdade7): trace topo-walk statistics
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> We trace statistics about the effectiveness of changed-path Bloom filters since [42e50e7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/42e50e78c6fd8978c2218bbd7b3483ae51d5e3f9) ("[`revision.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/42e50e78c6fd8978c2218bbd7b3483ae51d5e3f9/revision.c): add trace2 stats around Bloom filter usage", 2020-04-06, Git v2.27.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9b6606f43d55bbf33b9924d16e02e60e1c09660a) listed in [batch #6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b34789c0b0d3b137f0bb516b417bd8d75e0cb306)).
> Add similar tracing for the topo-walk algorithm that uses generation numbers to limit the walk size.
>
> This information can help investigate and describe benefits to heuristics and other changes.
>
> The information that is printed is in JSON format and can be formatted nicely to present as follows:
>
> ```
> {
> unt_explort_walked":2603,
> unt_indegree_walked":2603,
> unt_topo_walked":473
> }
> ```
>
> Each of these values count the number of commits are visited by each of the three "stages" of the topo-walk as detailed in [b454241](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b45424181e9e8b2284a48c6db7b8db635bbfccc8) ("[`revision.c`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/b45424181e9e8b2284a48c6db7b8db635bbfccc8/revision.c): generation-based topo-order algorithm", 2018-11-01, Git v2.20.0-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/62ca33e02a4ea93dd59538ac986a082430253b27)).

---

With Git 2.32 (Q2 2021), a new configuration variable has been introduced to allow choosing which version of the generation number gets used in the commit-graph file.

See [commit 702110a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/702110aac63556b4572d9c7b65c9123ec8038ebf), [commit c7ef8fe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c7ef8fe608819f05526408c741719589599a544a) (25 Feb 2021) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit d20fa3c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d20fa3cf9dba095b9d8836b177da697425ce8d3c), 22 Mar 2021)</sup>

> ### [`commit-graph`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/702110aac63556b4572d9c7b65c9123ec8038ebf): use config to specify generation type
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> We have two established generation number versions: 1: topological levels 2: corrected commit dates
>
> The corrected commit dates are enabled by default, but they also write extra data in the `GDAT` and `GDOV` chunks.
> Services that host Git data might want to have more control over when this feature rolls out than just updating the Git binaries.
>
> Add a new "`commitGraph.generationVersion`" config option that specifies the intended generation number version.
> If this value is less than 2, then the `GDAT` chunk is never written *or  read* from an existing file.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/702110aac63556b4572d9c7b65c9123ec8038ebf/Documentation/config/commitgraph.txt#L1-L6):

> ### `commitGraph.generationVersion`
>
> Specifies the type of generation number version to use when writing
> or reading the commit-graph file.
> If version 1 is specified, then
> the corrected commit dates will not be written or read.
>
> Defaults to 2.

Note: There was a bug in the codepath to upgrade generation information in commit-graph from v1 to v2 format, which has been corrected with Git 2.37.2 (Q3 2022).

See [commit 9550f6c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9550f6c16a8be18bd4868909d4d5e29d05bd9733), [commit 7805360](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7805360b7a3be02057385bc9d17aa493120b9538), [commit 2dd804c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2dd804cd12143741ea4188346fba250e821609b5) (12 Jul 2022) by [Taylor Blau (`ttaylorr`)](https://github.com/ttaylorr).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 37e4bdd](https://github.com/git/git/commit/37e4bdd5ee5d6a7e09feaf5857299aac8fd56aeb), 03 Aug 2022)</sup>

This avoids that subsequent reads using the commit-graph produce the following error message:

```
fatal: commit-graph requires overflow generation data but has none
```

---

Make sure to use Git 2.36+ (Q2 2022) though, as it fixes the way generation number v2 in the commit-graph files are (not) handled.

See [commit 6dbf4b8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6dbf4b8172ef9edd50bdf9ca2da4681ba9153f75) (02 Mar 2022), and [commit c8d67b9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c8d67b9a682e2a52beafab60f057ac317e35358d), [commit 3b0199d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/3b0199d4c3c9cc2ec39413c52c15cfd16e4d0980), [commit 75979d9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/75979d94607d92d53b1cad5d65f20594c66d275c), [commit 17925e0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/17925e0602983b1a1dbdd418c2fc2c70ca5faf5b), [commit c78c7a9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c78c7a959cacf20eb55a694ed9e20921afb306cf) (01 Mar 2022) by [Derrick Stolee (`derrickstolee`)](https://github.com/derrickstolee).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a54cc52](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a54cc523ad7736cb5768dc10c1873260738cb4a4), 16 Mar 2022)</sup>

> ### [`commit-graph`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6dbf4b8172ef9edd50bdf9ca2da4681ba9153f75): declare bankruptcy on GDAT chunks
>
> <sup>Reported-by: Patrick Steinhardt</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Derrick Stolee</sup>

> The **Generation Data** (**GDAT**) and **Generation Data Overflow** (**GDOV**) chunks store corrected commit date offsets, used for generation number v2.
> Recent changes have demonstrated that previous versions of Git were incorrectly parsing data from these chunks, but might have also been writing them incorrectly.
>
> [Patrick demonstrated](https://lore.kernel.org/git/Yh93vOkt2DkrGPh2@ncase/) a case where in split commit-graphs across an alternate boundary (and possibly some other special conditions) it was possible to have a commit-graph that was generated by a previous version of Git have incorrect generation number v2 data which results in errors like the following:
>
> ```
> commit-graph generation for commit <oid> is 1623273624 < 1623273710
> ```
>
> If we cannot trust the existing data in the GDAT and GDOV chunks, then we can alter the format to change the chunk IDs for these chunks.
> This causes the new version of Git to silently ignore the older chunks (and disabling generation number v2 in the process) while writing new commit-graph files with correct data in the GDA2 and GDO2 chunks.

`technical/commit-graph-format` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/6dbf4b8172ef9edd50bdf9ca2da4681ba9153f75/Documentation/technical/commit-graph-format.txt#L159-L166):

> ### Historical Notes:
>
> The Generation Data (GDA2) and Generation Data Overflow (GDO2) chunks have
> the number '2' in their chunk IDs because a previous version of Git wrote
> possibly erroneous data in these chunks with the IDs "GDAT" and "GDOV". By
> changing the IDs, newer versions of Git will silently ignore those older
> chunks and write the new information without trusting the incorrect data.

Comment: So to answer the question, the command to run is still `git rev-list --all --topo-order | grep --file SET_OF_SHA1S`, it just happens to be faster in Git 2.20?

Comment: Yes, that is the idea.

Comment: Of interest, [commit ae1b383](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ae1b383dfa945d98ec3cedd744619c2028d6edf7) from [commit 2da81d1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2da81d1efb0166e1cec7a8582b837994dde6225b)

Comment: Thanks, I've just got my problem solved/sorted by `git rev-list --topo-order --all 534a66 10377 c898a35 d1094 | grep -E '^(534a66|10377|c898a35|d1094)'`. Of course the list of SHAs was longer.

Comment: @quetzalcoatl Nice. That should work indeed.